# Accounting for upper limit in data input for ols estimator

Tags: r, statistics

I have a seemingly simple issue which i do not know how to solve.

We run a student cinema and I wanted to estimate how many visitors we will get based on how many likes on instagram we got.

**The problem** is that we can only fit 220 people in the room and because we get our visitor numbers from the sold tickets, the data for when we are sold out is severely distorted, pushing the overall estimate down.

My one idea for how to solve it is to run an OLS including only one sold out showing with the smallest nuzmber of likes to extrapolate how many visitors would have come in the other sold out shows and include those numbers instead of the repeating 220, but at that point it feels like i might as well just delete the sold out shows from the data.

How do i most elegantly account for this upper limit to get a more accurate predictor?

Comment: If the response must be between 0 and 220 divide it by 220 and use logistic regression.  The predictions will have to be multiplied by 220 to get back to the original scale.  Also with `glm` there will be a warning that the response is not 0/1 but it is just a warning and not an error since and it will still work.

Comment: This is a classic censored regression, and the workhorse is the Tobit model. It's available in the `censReg` package (not that I've used it). [This](https://bookdown.org/mattdobra/Prelude/censoredcount.html) introduction looks nice, and starts with an example similar to yours.  Throwing out the capped ("right-censored") values will flatten your estimate of the relationship between likes and demand because it biases the data in favour of including films with many likes that have a large negative residual, and hence fall short of the cap, while excluding those with a large positive residual.